# select number from list of string

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, replace

I want to convert list of strings to list of numbers but there is no luck

my string is like

```
x=[u'9-9', u'-5-5',u'-45-45',u'99-99']
```

i want to convert it to :

```
x=[9,-5,-45,99]
```

i tried to loop in the list and replace '-' using `string.replace('-','')` in each string in the list to remove the '-'  and divide the number into 2 paces but the string keep have the char '-' the replace doesn't work

some of my code :

```
import string
x=[u'9-9', u'-5-5',u'-45-45',u'99-99']
for i in x:
    string.replace(str(i),"-",' ')
    print i
```

output :

```
9-9
-5-5
-45-45
99-99
```

any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out strings in python are immutable. Operations on them return new strings instead of changing the original. Your output requirement is also a list of integers, so you have to parse the strings:

```
In [1]: x=[u'9-9', u'-5-5',u'-45-45',u'99-99']

In [2]: [int(i.rsplit('-', 1)[0]) for i in x]
Out[2]: [9, -5, -45, 99]
```

Using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) the string is [split starting from right](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) 1 time only using `'-'` as delimiter and the first string is picked up and parsed as integer.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression:

```
import re

x = [u'9-9', u'-5-5',u'-45-45',u'99-99']
regex = "([-]?\d*)-.*"

x = [int(re.search(regex, m).group(1)) for m in x]
print(x)
# [9, -5, -45, 99]
```

Answer (score 2):

`str.replace` is not in-place. It returns a new string with the replaced characters. Therefore:

```
for i in x:
    string.replace(str(i),"-",' ')
```

Doesn't affect the strings in `x` whatsoever.

You should also call `replace` directly on the string object you have, instead of calling the general `replace` from the `string` module.

Instead, what you should do is:

```
x = [u'9-9', u'-5-5',u'-45-45',u'99-99']
x_int = [int(string.replace('-', '')) for string in x]
print x_int
>> [99, 55, 4545, 9999]
```

And just a small bit of code to emphasis that `str.replace` returns a new string:

```
x = [u'9-9', u'-5-5',u'-45-45',u'99-99']
for i in x:
    print i.replace(,"-",'')
    print i
>> 99
   9-9
   55
   -5-5
   4545
   -45-45
   9999
   99-99
```

Comment: please add how could i divide the number in 2 parts and remove the second parts to be 
9 - 5 - 45 - 99

Answer (score 2):

id like to use e regular expressions. just take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-contents) and use [this](https://regex101.com/#) for composing a regexp

```
import re

x=[u'9-9', u'-5-5',u'-45-45',u'99-99']
rexp = '(.*)-\d+'
c = re.compile(rexp)
for i in x:
    print(int(c.search(i).groups()[0]))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re 

[int(re.sub(r"(-\d+$)", r"", i)) for i in x]
#[9, -5, -45, 99]
```